# Cannot understand this code snippet of C

Tags: c, for-loop, int, printf, short

my code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {

short int i=0;

for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i; i>0)
    printf("%d, ",i);

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-

i don't know from where it starts but end in the sequence

```
..., -4, -3, -2, -1
```

can u help me understand the working of this code snippet?

Comment: @KingsIndian As discussed below Daniel's answer, the consensual interpretation of the standard(s) is that `++i` should act as `i = (short)((int)i + 1);`. For this interpretation and for most architectures, there is therefore only implementation-defined conversion at the conversion to `short`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i; i>0)
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(; ++i;)
```

because `i<=5 && i>=-1` and `i > 0` expressions have no side-effects.

Now the controlling expression is `++i`, it means the loop is executed until `++i` is evaluated to `0`.

`i` is a `short` object so `++i` is equivalent to `i = (int) i + 1`.

When `(int) i + 1` is converted to `short` object `i` and the value is not representable in a `short`, the conversion is implementation defined (see C99, 6.3.1.3p3).

In your implementation the behavior is that when the value is not representable in a `short`, it just wraps around and becomes a huge negative value (`SHRT_MIN`). The loop is executed repeatedly until the `++i` controlling expression is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a malformed sentence, which is syntactically correct.
Instead of initialization that makes sense (e.g. i=0), it has a statement that evaluates to true. As the comparison it only increases the variable i and ends, when i reaches zero. The end statement to be performed after each successful iteration, does nothing.

The working part of the statement is equivalent to while (++i) printf("%d",i);
and (because of the properties of 2's complement numbers, it loops from 1,2,3,4,..., 32766,32767, and wraps to negative numbers
-32768, -32767, ..., -3,-2,-1. 
(and stops, at the next iteration when i == 0)

EDIT: The loop continues possibly forever until the condition i==0 is met. Integer calculation in computers is most usually calculated modulo 2^16 or modulo 2^32, modulo 2^64 etc. It just happens that it's very convenient to map the range of the available 65536 different values in 16 bit numbers to 2 ranges: 0...32767 and 32768...65535, where the latter part can be *interpreted* as positive integers [unsigned] or as negative integers with value of (x-65536). The c language keyword *signed* asks the computer to do just that.

Comment: but still i can't understand why the output contains that wrapping of negative numbers as well?

Comment: In binary, The largest short is represented as 0x7FFF (32767). If you add one to that, you should result with 0x8000, which is the smallest short you can have (-32768). This is why it goes from positive to negative.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: In range arithmetic the most fascinating fact is that the CPU doesn't need to know when adding or subtracting if the numbers are to be interpreted as signed or unsigned. Also this particular point is handy, as all those negative numbers have the most significant bit set -- which is also often called the _sign bit_.

Comment: Other computer languages e.g. Pascal by default uses cpu-inbuilt 'overflow' detection to ensure that positive+positive does not wrap. In those cases the execution would end abruptly probably with a cryptic error (exception) message.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
for(i<=5 && i>=-1; ++i; i>0)
```

this

```
i<=5 && i>=-1
```

means true, because `0 <= 5 and 0 >= -1`

And why you get -2, -1?
It's buffer overflow. When you add 1 to MAX_INT you will get negative number

```
01111
```

add 1

```
10000
```

First bit it's negative bit (1 - digital is negative, 0 - is positive)

Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Also you can try modify `int` to `unsigned int`

---

Output is

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
....
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1
```

You can check this by

```
 program.exe > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the clauses in your `for` loop confused, which is causing you to count up all the way to the maximum short integer value. When you add 1 to that, it loops around to the minimum short integer value, a negative number, and then keep counting up until it gets to 0, at which point the loop finally stops. The reason it loops around is because integers are generally stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), and most CPUs and compilers don't do anything special on overflow; they just keep adding, even if the result doesn't make sense. In two's complement, the maximum integer value is represented as `0111...`; when you add 1 to that, you get `1000...`, which is the minimum negative integer.

In a C for loop, the expressions are `for(initializer; condition; update) body`.

The *initializer* is run once at the beginning, to initialize any variables. Since you are just doing some comparisons, it basically does nothing in your loop.

The *condition* is run once per iteration, before running that iteration, to test to see if the loop should continue. Your *condition* is `++i`. This increments `i` (adds one to it) and returns the result. So on the first pass, `i` starts off at `0`, you increment it to `1`, and the `for` loop uses that value to decide if the loop should continue. Any number besides `0` is considered "true" in C, so the loop continues; ant it keeps going until you get to the point where `i` is `-1`, so that incrementing it leaves you with `0`, which is a false value.

The *update* expression is run once per iteration, after the body, to update any variables you might need to continue the iteration. You are simply doing a comparison here, for which it doesn't use the value, so you are basically doing nothing.

In the end, your for loop is basically the same as:

```
for (;++i;)
    printf("%d, ",i);
```

Which is also the same as:

```
while (++i)
    printf("%d, ",i);
```

What you probably meant instead is:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    printf("%d, ",i);
```